# Trying to create stored procedure with parameter and multiple joins

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, stored-procedures, outer-join

I'm trying to create a stored procedure with one parameter and joining three tables: `OrdersOrders`, `Ordered_ProductsOrdered_Products` and `ProductsProducts`. I want columns from all the tables that does not have matching tables. The parameter is used in java for the costumer to be able to search order based on their user ID.

This is what I've come up with:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_seeOrder
    @user_id
AS
    SELECT 
        O.order_id, O.order_quantity, O.user_id, O.Status, O.order_date, 
        O_P.orderID, O_P.product_code, 
        P.product_id, P.product_name, P.price
    FROM 
        Orders AS O
    FULL JOIN 
        Ordered_Products ON O.order_id = O_P.orderID,
    RIGHT JOIN 
        Products P ON O_P.product_code = P.product_id
    WHERE 
        user_id = @user_id;
```

I get multiple errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_seeOrder, Line 4 [Batch Start Line 213]
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_seeOrder, Line 9 [Batch Start Line 213]
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'RIGHT'.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  You should probably also be quite clear on what you want the code to do.  I also strongly discourage your from using a stored procedure for a simple query.  A view or table-function (assuming your database supports them) is preferred.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thank you for your answer Gordon. The database is local, this is for a school assignment, so I can't tag it. I want to be able to get information in columns from three tables who are connected through keys between them. I changed it to a view and removed the parameter, but I still get one error (I edited my original post)

Comment: This bit _Procedure sp_seeOrder_ tells us that what you think you are doing is not what you posted.

Comment: Sorry SMor, I edited the question since I was adviced to changed it to a view, and I was a bit fast on the keyboard. But I got my answer to fix the syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a data type in the @user_id parameter. I assumed that it is an INT since it is an ID. And remove the extra , after the "ON O.order_id = O_P.orderID". The corrected query should look like this:

```
CREATE PROC sp_seeOrder
@user_id INT
AS
SELECT 
    O.order_id, O.order_quantity, O.user_id, O.Status, O.order_date, O_P.orderID, 
    O_P.product_code, P.product_id, P.product_name, P.price
FROM Orders AS O
FULL JOIN Ordered_Products AS O_P
    ON O.order_id = O_P.orderID
RIGHT JOIN Products P
    ON O_P.product_code = P.product_id
WHERE user_id = @user_id;
```